# Add a product carousel to a different page template

Tags: bigcommerce

I'm using bigcommerce, I have the theme called Peak, which I believe is a stencil theme.

I'm not a developer by any means. I searched here but could not find an answer - I apologise if this is already out there somewhere but i did look.

I want to be able to add a different carousel (different pictures, phrases etc) on different pages of my site.

Can this be done with ease?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a carousel to different pages in BigCommerce theme can be done with ease. It depends on how much familiar you are but you will need some programming skills to modify theme or you can try copy pasting content of current page into new page and see if carousel comes up there. From your question it looks like you will need some development as you want different carousel on each page and pages can be using different code that need modification.

Comment: Thank you. I have zero programming skills. Sounds like we need a developer then.

Comment: Can you provide an actual walk through?